# Set the value of textfield in an inner layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I want to set the value of a textfield in an inner layout. 
This is my parent xml(outer layout).

**activity_navigator.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >

     </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**nav_header_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_background"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="119dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:id="@+id/userTextView"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I wanto set the value of the text field **userTextView** from navigator.kt class

**navigator.kt**

```
       override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigator)
//getting exception here
                  val userTextView: TextView= findViewById<TextView>(R.id.userTextView)
           Log.d("usertextview",userTextView.toString())

                }
```

Please help me solve this.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: You are using the wrong id of your textview. In your layout, you have declared id as userName and in the code you are referring to userTextView

Comment: @Gautam Sorry that was the mistake when I copied the code snippet. Actually i gave the correct id

Comment: @AmruthaJRaj then what error you are getting?

Comment: @Gautam Got the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this in your **navigator.kt**

get your navigation `headerview` and set text to `TextView`. Like this

```
    lateinit var  navView:View
    lateinit var  txt_name : TextView

    navView = nav_view.getHeaderView(0)

    txt_name = navView.findViewById(R.id.userName) as TextView
    txt_name.text = "user"
```